# Doesn't Female Titan and Beast Titan have the Coordinate ability?

Tags: attack-on-titan

It seems like most titans have the `Coordinate` ability. Beast Titan was directly telling other titans what to do. Female was calling and leading them.

Whats the difference in Eren's Coordinate ability? They look the same to me. Or is it the same power like regeneration but only some titans have it?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/40949/if-the-beast-titan-has-similar-powers-to-the-founding-titan-why-do-they-need-it

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** (or avoiding spoilers)

The Beast Titan and Female Titan have shown *some* control over the titans, but they have limitations and do not provide they same control over the Titans as The Coordinate does.

Titans submit to the will of the user with The Coordinate. The Beast Titan requires verbal commands and the Female Titan can only attract through her screams

---

[Beast Titan](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Beast_Titan)

> Zeke's Beast Titan is able to exercise some control over mindless Titans through a scream-based ability. Through vocal commands, the Beast Titan is able to direct the actions of mindless Titans and can command them to refrain from eating humans and stay in place if necessary. Titans under Zeke's control are even able to function using only moonlight without falling into fatigue. However, this ability is evidently imperfect in comparison to the Founding Titan. Titans under the control of the Beast Titan either seem to be capable of ignoring orders or occasionally do not receive or comprehend orders given. Furthermore, Titans under the Beast Titan's control cannot act upon the unspoken will of the Beast's user, unlike the Founding Titan, and must be given some sort of direct verbal signal before taking action.

[Female Titan](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Female_Titan#cite_note-m27p27-33-1)

> Like the Founding Titan and the Beast Titan, the Female Titan is able to exercise some influence over mindless Titans through a scream-based ability; it possesses the ability to attract mindless Titans over long distances. It has been theorized that this ability was used by Annie Leonhart to gather all the Titans on the island of Paradis to the Walls during the fall of Wall Maria.

[The Coordinate](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Founding_Titan)

> The Founding Titan, also translated as Progenitor Titan) is the first of the Nine Titans, granting its user the unique ability to control the actions of the Titans, modify the memories of others in the majority bloodline of the Walls, and inherit the memories of those who previously possessed the ability. It is commonly known to the Marley military as the "Coordinate", the point where the "paths" of all the subjects of Ymir, including Titans, converge

Comment: Inheriting the memories of the previous titan shifter is not exclusive to the founding titan. Other titan shifters can, to some extent, gain access to the memories, too.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Female titan and Beast titan do not have *the* coordinate ability. The major difference is that Eren can fully control a titan, he can do everything that the Female and Beast titans do, but more exact. The Beast and Female titans can guide and take a general control as if telling them what to do like a parent to a child. It is pointed out in the manga that Zeke Yeager's ability is special to him and he is the only Beast titan to have it. The reason for Zeke's advanced ability is his blood, he is directly related to the original titan, as for Annie, it is believed that she is also directly related, but it isn't yet proven.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong. So it has been stated that for the Beast Titan, he has a spinal fluid that if entered into a Subject of Ymir, he can guide and control those specific ones, even making them transform to pure titans (as how it was shown during season 3 part 2 in the battle of shiganshina. The beast titan shows up and many others are shown to transform and you see titans under his guidance.

As for the Female Titan, either she has that ability to call SOME titans when screaming OR it was because the Beast Titan was around there and heard the scream, thus aided Annie at the time.